# Edgy plot of a minute interval time series with POSIXct format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series, posixct

first of all thank you for the help! I tried to plot a stock price for which the time interval is of very 5 minutes. The resulting plot is very edgy if I plot it as a time series. It's correct if I simply plot the price as if it's a sequence of numbers.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)

Symb <- "spot"
intv<- "5min"

stock_daily <- tq_get(Symb, get = "alphavantage", av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", interval = "5min", outputsize = "full")
```

Here is the data:

```
> dput(head(stock_daily, 20))
structure(list(symbol = c("spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", 
"spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", 
"spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot", "spot"), timestamp = structure(c(1591349700, 
1591350000, 1591350300, 1591350600, 1591350900, 1591351200, 1591351500, 
1591351800, 1591352100, 1591352400, 1591352700, 1591353000, 1591353300, 
1591353600, 1591353900, 1591354200, 1591354500, 1591354800, 1591355100, 
1591355400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    open = c(179, 179.38, 180.53, 182.5249, 183.1, 183.4, 183.71, 
    183.76, 182.705, 181.92, 181.87, 181.9626, 181.99, 181.75, 
    182.29, 181.9, 181.56, 181.309, 181.37, 181.06), high = c(179.78, 
    181.51, 182.59, 183.48, 183.665, 183.79, 183.99, 184.155, 
    182.82, 182.19, 181.99, 182.4, 182.23, 182.27, 182.38, 181.91, 
    181.6, 181.7, 181.51, 181.1673), low = c(177.505, 179.33, 
    180.3, 182.18, 182.955, 182.83, 183.17, 182.64, 181.71, 181.09, 
    181.48, 181.62, 181.43, 181.75, 181.9, 181.43, 181.32, 181.2872, 
    181.02, 180.37), close = c(179.4, 180.6, 182.3, 183.11, 183.4685, 
    183.68, 183.655, 182.72, 182.08, 181.66, 181.99, 181.77, 
    181.6277, 182.27, 181.91, 181.6138, 181.51, 181.435, 181.1, 
    180.37), volume = c(55046, 24842, 20192, 13935, 19356, 19911, 
    11355, 12081, 11462, 9882, 5826, 8278, 5058, 6790, 4437, 
    6248, 4489, 9217, 4638, 12602)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
#This gives the edgy line when the x-axis consists of time:
plot(stock_daily$timestamp, stock_daily$open, type = "l")
```

[Edgy plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFxO4.png)

```
#This gives the smooth line when the x-axis is of index form: 
plot(stock_daily$open, type = "l")
```

[Smooth plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1lXF.png)

I tried to convert the data stock_daily to a xts object but it doesn't work. I suspect this might be because that the time interval is not equally divided, for example the data is provided at 2020-06-23 11:30:00, but then the next one is 2020-06-23 11:45:00. It skipped 11:35:00 and 11:40:00. However I added these two missing rows with values as NA and tried again, it still didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including some data which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You could use `dput(head(your_data, 20))`. - I tried running your code and it needs an "Alpha Vantager API key". Also if you have a bit of time: have a look at https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5 and [mre]

Comment: @Peter Hi Peter thank you so much! Sorry for the inconvenience, as I'm really new to stack overflow and I didn't know how to add my data here. Let me figure this out first and get back to you!

Comment: @Peter Hi Peter I took your advice to use dput and added the data sample. Please let me know if you need anything! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that you loaded ggplot2 and ended using plot.

Here's your edgy plot in ggplot

```
ggplot(stock_daily, aes(x=timestamp, y = open)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Using smoother for the same timestamp:

```
ggplot(stock_daily, aes(x=timestamp, y = open)) + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for the quick response! I use plot just to keep things simple and straight to the issue. UnfortunatelyI can't use geom_smooth because I need to see the original stock price and I'll later add other plots on top of it. Could you teach me how to get the "Smooth plot" I pasted in the question? Thank you so much!

Comment: oh and this issue doesn't occur if I plot daily prices. You can change av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY" and delete interval=intv to get the daily price.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of issue. The data is not continuous like time, for example there's no data during the weekend. The plot or ggplot function connects lines between each data point but the points are not equally spaced, hence we see those long lines in the edgy plot. The solution is to use other plot functions like chartSeries(), which is specifically designed for financial data modelling. Or we can convert the time series as a data frame in which the time index is saved as a separate column. This way we can plot the data, and add the time column as x labels.

There's another post for the similar issue:
[ggplot: Plotting timeseries data with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648800/ggplot-plotting-timeseries-data-with-missing-values)